# How to build a model creating shp polygonal objects using for that the parameters of xls file?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder

Could somebody advise which instrument I can use in  ModelBuilder (ArcGIS10) for build a model which will create shp polygonal objects from a table (created previously in Excel) with necessary parameters (that include coordinates of latitude and longitude and distances).

Some details.
I need to create many polygonal objects by 4 steps:

1. Create 2 circles with the same center (with coordinates X1, Y2 – they will be in the table) and radiuses Rmax and Rmin (they will be in the table);
2. Create a new polygonal object (“bagel”) = Circle (max) – Circle(min);
3. Create a polygon triangle by coordinates of 3 their vertexes (all coordinates will be in the table);
4. Find a resulting polygonal object (as a shapefile) that will be equal a space of intersection of “bagel” and that triangle.

Comment: Having a model do all of that off of 1 file would be extremely difficult. If you want to automate that, you'd be better off scripting it.

Comment: Thank you, Paul.
But is it possible to create polygonal objects in ArcGIS (I think by ModelBuilder) by dint of parameters of a table? 

Not necessary to do it in one file or at one step. If I’ll know the way how I can do it, 
maybe I can do it by some steps in ModelBuilder or by script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To draw a circle, you could use the [Create Ellipse
   tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000tt000000)
   (Just specify the major and minor axes to have the same radius) or
   take a look at [this
   post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5574/how-to-create-a-circle-in-arcpy).
2. The [Erase tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Erase/00080000000m000000/) can be used to create a "bagel" polygon.
3. For creating the polygons, you can use
   [arcpy.Polygon()](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000061000000)
   which takes an array of vertices to create your polygon. I don't
   think you have access to it in Model Builder, though.
4. I think you'll want the [Intersect tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Intersect/00080000000p000000/) to compute the area of overlap between your bagel and triangle.

Another option for steps 1/2 would be to create points for the center of your circles and run the [Multiple Ring Buffer tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001p000000) with both of the radii as inputs. You can then delete the smaller circles, thereby giving you your bagels.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Paul, your answers were very helpful!

On another resource people advised me two more ways for create polygonal objects (no circle) from coordinates in a table, I put them here:

1. http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15974

Script: Convert Points to Polygons - Generic Tool

Creates an output polygon feature class based on point features and a field representing unique output features. An optional parameter can be used to control the order in which the input points are used. Version ArcGIS = 9.3-10 (maybe later as well)
I tested – it works (creates polygonal objects using a shp theme of points for it (so I had to prepare this point shp  theme from my xls table at first)

2.ET Geo Wizard

http://www.ian-ko.com/

I didn’t test it yet. But I suppose it’s a free operation “Point to Polygon”.