# How to create Circle using X,Y Coordinate and radius by ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I have been given three parameters X and Y coordinates and a distance or the radius of the circle.
I will have to draw a circle using ArcPy by these three parameters where the center is the point of X-Y coordinate and radius is distance.

e.g: Center (20.5937° N, 78.9629° E) 
     Radius 5 unit

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this answer might help although it is a few years old: [How to create a circle in arcpy](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5574/how-to-create-a-circle-in-arcpy/5577#5577)

Comment: The magnitude of your "X,Y" value implies decimal degrees, and your radius of "5 units" is exceedingly vague.  Please edit the question to specify the projection and radius units.

Comment: yes the coordinate is in degrees i.e the lat and long of a place which will be the center of the Circle and the unit of the radius is double

Comment: You've got your X and Y values flipped (longitude is X, latitude is Y).  A buffer of 5 units makes no sense -- What units?  Cartesian Degrees?  (Cartesian degrees are useless because the ground distance varies by center location (latitude); this is particularly true when a large area is involved).

Comment: Please post code as text rather than pictures of code.  That way it is available for future searches and potential answerers can copy/paste for any necessary testing.

Comment: import math
import arcpy
def circle_poly(x,y,r): 
    for i in range(100):
        ang = i/100 * math.pi * 2
        yield (x + r * math.cos(ang), y + r * math.sin(ang) )
x = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
y = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
distance = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
res = circle_poly(x,y,distance)

Answer (score 2):

You could create a buffer around the point using the buffer command. For example in 10.0 using arcpy.Buffer_analysis(), and use the radius as the buffer distance.
Check this link : http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000800000019000000.htm