# How to create Geodesic Polygons in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2

I would like to create geodesic polygons in openlayers. This is not the same as [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3264/using-geodesic-measurements-for-cirle-radii) although VERY similar.

[Geographika](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/186/geographika) was able to do it but [his solution](http://geographika.co.uk/creating-a-geodesic-circle-in-openlayers) is based on a circle. I'm interested in creating polygons that aren't necessarily circles, such as squares. Or maybe even a line.

Anyone know of any javascript snippet that might convert my geometric openlayers polygons to geodesic ones?

Google Maps has the Geodesic:true property for its shapes. OpenLayers should definitely have it.

Comment: How exactly are you constructing your polygons? Through the OpenLayers tools or in code with distances?

Comment: @geographika: I'm constructing them mostly using OpenLayers.Format.WKT `var myFeature = format.read("POLYGON((-102.65625 5.2734375, -109.6875 -42.5390625, 97.03125 -39.7265625, 99.140625 6.6796875, -102.65625 5.2734375))");`

Comment: Actually the user has the option of drawing a polygon on the map with the OpenLayers tools as well. But for simplicity sake, let's just suppose i'm using the Format.WKT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only have two points on a line you may have to create more vertices and then reproject these to EPSG:4326 and back again to create something similar to the [Google example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geometry-headings).

There is an OpenLayers example of Great Circle lines [here](http://gis.ibbeck.de/ginfo/apps/OLExamples/OL26/examples/gc_example.html). The source code for the algorithms is also [online](http://gis.ibbeck.de/ginfo/apps/OLExamples/OL26/examples/javascript/greatcirclemod.js).

There is a [getGeodesicArea](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Polygon-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.getGeodesicArea) function on OpenLayer polygons, and [geometry collections](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Collection-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.Collection). There is also a [getGeodesicLength](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Collection-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.Collection.getGeodesicLength) function. These algorithms are implemented based on the following (according to the docs):

> Robert.  G. Chamberlain and William H.  Duquette, “Some Algorithms for
>   Polygons on a Sphere”, JPL Publication 07-03, Jet Propulsion
>   Laboratory, Pasadena, CA, June 2007
>   http://trs-new.jpl.nasa.gov/dspace/handle/2014/40409

Looking at the [sourcecode](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Geometry/Curve.js) it reprojects points to 4326, and then uses the [OpenLayers.Util.distVincenty](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Util.js#L728) function to calculate the distance between points on the surface of an ellipsoid (the earth).

```
getGeodesicLength: function(projection) {
    var geom = this; // so we can work with a clone if needed
    if(projection) {
        var gg = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
        if(!gg.equals(projection)) {
            geom = this.clone().transform(projection, gg);
        }
    }
    var length = 0.0;
    if(geom.components && (geom.components.length > 1)) {
        var p1, p2;
        for(var i=1, len=geom.components.length; i<len; i++) {
            p1 = geom.components[i-1];
            p2 = geom.components[i];
            // this returns km and requires lon/lat properties
            length += OpenLayers.Util.distVincenty(
                {lon: p1.x, lat: p1.y}, {lon: p2.x, lat: p2.y}
            );
        }
    }
    // convert to m
    return length * 1000;
}
```

For polygons areas, the algorithm is in the [LinearRing source](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Geometry/LinearRing.js), and uses the earth's radius of 6378137 and geometry to calculate the geodesic area.

```
getGeodesicArea: function(projection) {
    var ring = this; // so we can work with a clone if needed
    if(projection) {
        var gg = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
        if(!gg.equals(projection)) {
            ring = this.clone().transform(projection, gg);
        }
    }
    var area = 0.0;
    var len = ring.components && ring.components.length;
    if(len > 2) {
        var p1, p2;
        for(var i=0; i<len-1; i++) {
            p1 = ring.components[i];
            p2 = ring.components[i+1];
            area += OpenLayers.Util.rad(p2.x - p1.x) *
                    (2 + Math.sin(OpenLayers.Util.rad(p1.y)) +
                    Math.sin(OpenLayers.Util.rad(p2.y)));
        }
        area = area * 6378137.0 * 6378137.0 / 2.0;
    }
    return area;
},
```

The main problem I had with the circle was that I only had one reference coordinate, and there was no inbuilt way in OpenLayers to create a circle around this point apart from on a Cartesian plane. However with the [OpenLayers.Util.distVincenty](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Util.js#L728) function it was relatively easy to calculate these.

Answer (score 2):

This patch to OpenLayers,

http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/ticket/3426

provides accurate geodesic calculations including the ability
to compute the area of a geodesic polygon accurately.

http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/scripts/geod-calc.html

previews some of the capabilities (including giving the area
of the polygon).

Comment: See also this paper: C. F. F. Karney, Algorithms for Geodesics, J. Geod, DOI: dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00190-012-0578-z