# ArcGIS Error 000861: Input feature is not valid

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, csv, inverse-distance-weighted, arcgis-10.8

I am trying to execute IDW of dataset (.csv format) in ArcGIS 10.8. But it is showing following error

[image]

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What if you export your csv layer to a file geodatabase feature class then try with this as input?

Comment: Please always provide error messages as formatted text rather than pictures.

Answer (score 0):

IDW only accepts a feature layer as an input.  Your CSV values (although they display in your MDX) are an event layer. As @BERA suggests, export your event layer to a feature class and try again. [See this link](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/idw.htm) for tool parameters.  For more information on the proper coordinate reference systems for IDW interpolations [consider this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58105/should-point-data-be-equidistant-projected-when-using-arcgis-idw-spatial-interpo).