# What equations does ArcGIS use to calculate X,Y coordinates from latitude and longitude?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.0

I am using the  NAD 1983 2011 UTM Zone 13N system for my data in ArcGIS. I really want to know how the equations ArcGIS used to calculate the X and Y.

[image]

Comment: There is an open source library, https://proj4.org/about.html - written in C and C++ for doing coordinate transforms if you really want to know how this can be done - ArcGIS is proprietary software and so beyond trusting the documentation you can't be sure how they do it.

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1237/seeking-introductory-texts-about-coordinate-system-projections/1262#1262  Particularly look at Snyder's Map Projections. Esri's algorithm is close to Snyder's for normal zone/data.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you have a look at Esri's page on [Geographic Transformation Methods](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/map-projections/geographic-transformation-methods.htm). In it, they explain that

> A geographic transformation always converts geographic
>   (latitude–longitude) coordinates. Some methods convert the geographic
>   coordinates to geocentric (X,Y,Z) coordinates, transform the X,Y,Z
>   coordinates, and convert the new values back to geographic
>   coordinates.

[Equation Based Methods](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/map-projections/equation-based-methods.htm) describes four methods for converting coordinates:

- [Three-parameter methods](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/map-projections/equation-based-methods.htm#GUID-2B38CE2E-8DE5-42B0-91F7-7D0278FCC4AF)
- [Seven-parameter methods](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/map-projections/equation-based-methods.htm#GUID-DF6B1DD1-B739-4030-A3EE-70150BA3B59E)
- [Molodensky method](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/map-projections/equation-based-methods.htm#GUID-7A49C102-88C3-4CB6-A756-9496208B7E91)
- [Abridged Molodensky method](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/map-projections/equation-based-methods.htm#GUID-13BE47A6-AA74-47CF-9801-5BB28BF2659F)

This page on [grid based methods](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/map-projections/grid-based-methods.htm) is also likely relevant.

Also have a look at this technical article [How To: Determine which NAD_1983_To_WGS_1984 transformation to use](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000005929).

I'm unsure which method above was used for your specific calculations.

Comment: OP asked a UTM projection aka how does transverse Mercator work, not about converting between geographic coordinate reference systems. Sorry, but downvote.